# 1 buy or sell per candle function at mql5

Tags: mql5

Am asking someone who is good at mql5 programming and do a function which allows trade only once per candle, the IsNewbar function only work at beginning of candle. Below is my try of making the function.

```
bool Tradeallowed(){

      bool hastraded = false;
      
    for(int a =PositionsTotal()-1;a>=0;a--){
         
         string symbol1 = PositionGetSymbol(a);  
         
         if(Symbol() == symbol1){
                  
            ulong pticket1 = PositionGetTicket(a);
            double csl1 = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL);
            int posT = PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE);
          
               if(posT == POSITION_TYPE_BUY || posT == POSITION_TYPE_SELL && 
                 
                  NewBar() == false){
                       hastraded = true;
                }
         }
     return hastraded;    
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a resource where you get your requirements coded for free. You should attempt to research and come up with a solution yourself. If you are then having problems you will receive much more help by posting what you have tried. Please read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simplify things. Rather that looking up orders which is unnecessary and prone to further problems, just record the candle time of the last trade.

```
datetime LastTrade;

void OnTick()
{
   if(LastTrade!=iTime(_Symbol,_Period,0))
   {
      // Place Trade Code Here
      LastTrade=iTime(_Symbol,_Period,0);
   }
}
```